# TypeError: me() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a supybot plugin but I keep getting an error and I was unable to fix (I use Python 2.6)

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supybot/callbacks.py", line 1180, in _callCommand
    self.callCommand(command, irc, msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supybot/utils/python.py", line 86, in g
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supybot/callbacks.py", line 1166, in callCommand
    method(irc, msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supybot/commands.py", line 913, in newf
    f(self, irc, msg, args, *state.args, **state.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supybot/plugins/Slap1/plugin.py", line 109, in slap
    self.me(irc, text)
TypeError: me() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
ERROR 2013-03-19T15:13:13 supybot Exception id: 0x873c0
```

Plugin code can be found here:

https://raw.github.com/StevenRKM/supybot-plugins/master/Slap/plugin.py

Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `me` method has the following signature: `def me(self, msg)`. And it is being called as `self.me(irc, text)` which would require the signature to be `def me(self, irc, msg)`.

Comment: Thank you Michael, the issue has been fixed

Answer (score 2):

I think the message gives a very strong clue as to what's wrong.

You are calling `me()` with three arguments (`self`, `irc` and `text`) whereas it is expecting two (`self` and `msg`).